# Use a get parameter as a function name

Tags: clojure, ring

this is my clojure-ring handler

```
(defn handler [req]
  (let [distr (get-in req [:query-params "dist"])]
    (def sortie (describe (eval ((resolve (symbol distr)) 1 3))
                         0.5 0.25 3))
    {:status 200
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
     :body (str "<p>" (print-str sortie) "<p>")}
  ))

(def app
  (-> #'handler
    (ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace)
    (wrap-spy)
    (wrap-params)
    ))
```

the "dist" key maps to a string.

```
:query-params {"dist" "gaussian-dist"}
```

I want to use it as a function name.
The whole

```
(eval ((resolve (symbol distr)) 1 3))
```

returns a map

When I replace distr by the string, it works as desired.

```
=> (eval ((resolve (symbol "gaussian-dist")) 1 3))
{:Distribution :actuarial.distributions/Gaussian, :Parameters {:sigma 3, :mu 1}}
```

**Edit:**

This is how I ended up solving my problem:
Thanks again, I'm a beginner at Clojure

I got through it using a macro

```
(defmacro get-map [map name]
  `(get ~map ~name))

(defn handler [req]
  (let [distr-name (get-in req [:query-params "dist"])
        distr-map ((get-map distributions-map distr-name) 1 3)
        sortie (describe distr-map 0.5 0.25 3)
        ]

    {:status 200
     :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
     :body (str "<p>" sortie "<p>")}))
```

Comment: It seems most likely that the value of `distr` is not as expected, could you put in a println, or otherwise inspect it, and include the output?

Comment: Do not use def inside functions. `sortie` can be replaced by another request before you use it.

Comment: This macro isn't doing anything you couldn't do with a function, and more simply too: `(defn get-map [map name] (get map name))`, or really `(def get-map get)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit of a risky proposition from a security and maintainability standpoint to let the Internet call any symbol in your namespace as a function, so my thought would be to instead do something like:

Prepare a white-list of functions users should be able to request, in the form of a map from query parameter strings to functions.

```
(def distributions {"gaussian-dist" gaussian-dist})
```

Make a default function which either makes an error message or just picks some default distribution.
When you get a query, just look up the function you need in `distributions` using `get` and the default function to handle the case of query strings not found.

```
(let [distr (get-in req [:query-params "dist"])
      sortie ((get distributions distr default-fn) 1 3)]
```

It's also kinda risky to `def` a var like `sortie` every request, as that opens you up to race conditions. That's why it seemed more natural to `let` that name too unless there's more to the handler than I'm seeing here. You might also be able to do what you want with `(def ^:dynamic *sortie*)` and `binding`, which isolates the bindings of different threads from one another to prevent that.

Comment: It isn't just "kinda risky" to def a symbol in a request handler, it is just plain wrong. Vars are globally accessible mutable state with no concurrency mechanism.